# Trying to get data from a child component will always return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I could not find a solution yet for my little issue. As I needed to change somebodies code I ran into an issue with getting data from the child component. The issue for what I can see is that the child component is NOT rendered before that I want to access it. I cant move the forms into the template variable scope so thats not a option. After rendering the child component I wanted to do some more stuff thats why I needed the data of the child.

Notice that the child component is a third party component.

**parent template**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="FormSubmit()">
  // some inputs here
  <button>print QR</button>
</form>

[more forms ...]

// this will ONLY be renderd if I click the print button!
<div *ngIf="qrCodeData">
  <qrcode #qrBlock [qrdata]="qrCodeData"></qrcode>
</div>
```

**Parent Component**

```
@ViewChild('qrBlock') set qrBlock(qrBlock: QRCodeComponent) {
  this.test = qrBlock
}

FormSubmit(): void {
   // setting up qr code data
   this.qrCodeData = [data]

   console.log(this.test)// will return undefined
   setTimeout(() => console.log(this.test) ,5000);// will return the data
}
```

Comment: Since you set `this.qrCodeData = [data]` in `FormSubmit()` there is no chance to get a value for `this.test` within the same Change Detection Cycle. Thats why you either have to apply `this.cd.detectChanges()` or to subscribe to the changes of `@ViewChild`. Both solutions seem quite hacky to me but I'd probably prefer using `this.cd.detectChanges()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[hidden]="!qrLoaded"` instead of `*ngIf="qrLoaded"`
or `@ViewChild('qrBlock',{static:true})`.

Comment: the use of static true will still return undefined

Comment: `static: false` is the default value while `static: true` is more restrictive than the default, so I don't think changing the static-value helps. => When the static property is set to false, the query for the child element or component is run every time the change detection cycle runs.

Comment: @user759235 you can check this example  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6kdmvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Your example will work but I would guess that using change detection is more hacky than a real solution?

Comment: as mentionned @kellermat static: false is the default value and the doc says  :                    static :- True to resolve query results before change detection runs,
     * false to resolve after change detection. Defaults to false.  so the only solution is to trigger the change detction manually

Comment: I changed the above example to align it with the answer I posted below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5vdenv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: In my stackblitz example above I didn't use `ChangeDetectorRef` and it still works.

Comment: @kellermat  as mentionned in the comments above with hidden there's another problem for him

Answer (score 0):

When using ViewChild you will have to wait for the component to render.

You have to put your code in the `ngAfterViewInit()` method otherwise `this.test` will remain undefined.

something like:

```
@ViewChild('qrBlock') qrBlock!: QRCodeComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.qrLoaded = true //EDIT: forgot this part
  this.test = this.qrBlock
  console.log(this.test) //component will be rendered here
}
```

To use `ngAfterViewInit()` you will have to implement it like the example below:

```
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
...
}
```

Comment: Yet if user759235 uses `[hidden]` on `</qrcode>` and then does a `console.log()` inside `FormSubmit()`, the `ngAfterViewInit()` should not be needed because the `ViewChild` should have been set long before this.

Comment: I don't know if it's more "error proof" the doc specify the `afterViewInit` hook "Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views". I think both ways works. 
[Source](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: still undefined, and I cant use [hidden] as this will give me a another error

Comment: I forgot to set `this.qrLoaded = true` in `ngAfterViewInit` in my code snippet

Comment: ngAfterViewInit will output undefined as the child is NOT rendered and will only be rendered when I click on the button

Comment: I just edited my response with the missing `this.qrLoaded = true`